# Unable to get Ajax respond from Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a simple endpoint for Nodejs but it doesn't work. Here is my folder structure

**index.js** (located in root/src)

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
path = require('path');
//init the app by serving index file
var app = express();
var port= process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get('/endpoint',function(req,res) {
    console.log("clicked");
    res.send("hey");
})
app.listen(port);
```

**index.html** (located in root/public):

I was unable to type out the html element here... but there is just a button with id=test enclosed in a div

**app.js** (located in root/public/js)

```
$('#test').on('click',function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/endpoint",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
})
```

The result that the console prints out is the HTML content of the whole index.html page instead of just the word "hey" (my Git console doesn't print out the word "clicked" either which means my app.get /enpoint is doing nothing).

**UPDATE**: I found the reason
in my index.js I was having this

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
});
```

The purpose of this is to prevent "cannot GET" error when user reload the page after going into some other template. When I removed it everything works as intended (except now users will get error if they reload the page)

Comment: I am not a NodeJS expert. Could it be that you should change the request type from GET to POST?

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. What version of node/express/jQuery are you using?

Comment: Only thing that could *possibly* be causing problems here is you run your app from a sub directory and the path for static is relative. You can try using an absolute path - `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`. Express could just be getting confused here.

Comment: It's unclear why you would get errors when the user reloads the page as that should not happen in a properly designed site.  You should probably solve that problem rather than attempt a work-around that messes up other things.